# QGIS launch errors with OpenSUSE Leap 15.3

Tags: gdal, qgis-3, linux, quickosm

I have upgraded my OpenSUSE Leap system from 15.2 to 15.3 recently.

I am now unable to launch QGIS properly. I get 2 error messages:

```
Couldn't load plugin 'QuickOSM' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method
Couldn't load plugin 'processing'
```

After I ignore the second message, QGIS crashes and I have to kill the process to exit.

Both messages talks about `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdal'` .

Here are my QGIS installation details:

```
Python version: 3.6.15 (default, Sep 23 2021, 15:41:43) [GCC] 
QGIS version: 3.18.0-Zürich Zürich, exported
```

Please notice that on the screenshot below, there seems to be inconsistencies concerning **GEOS** and **SQLite** compiled and running versions... But I don't know how to address such a problem, if it could explain the issue described here (?).

[image]

I have tried to uninstall QGIS and reinstall both LTR and last available versions, either from [official repository](http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/$releasever/repo/oss/) or from [Application:Geo](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Application:/Geo/openSUSE_Leap_15.3/) one.

Owing to [OpenSUSE official documentation](https://software.opensuse.org/package/qgis), there would not exist any official QGIS package for OpenSUSE Leap 15.3 version of the system... Which really is a surprise to me, as the 15.3 version has been released in June 2021.

How can I bring my QGIS back on the rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I had an initial installation from a name 'Geo' repository:

https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Application:/Geo/openSUSE_Leap_15.3/

The following command returned all packages installed from this repo:

```
zypper se -sir https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Application:/Geo/openSUSE_Leap_15.3/
```

I then used *YaST2* to switch one by one every package installed from 'Geo' repository to the official OSS one.

I then disabled the Geo repository and did a computer reboot.

After reboot, I installed *QGIS* via *YaST2* and it now runs again perfectly!

See this [post](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/567115-QGIS-launch-errors-with-OpenSUSE-Leap-15-3) that provided help to fix my issue.

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks and a sign-off in your posts.

Answer (score 1):

I've just updated to 15.3 and installed QGIS via (YaST software) and it works perfectly. QGIS version 3.18. This is my config:

[image]

Check if you have the correct gdal and spatialite version:

[image]

It could be good to remove completely QGIS, including folder in user hiden dirs, where those plugins are stored. Then do a fresh install.